# SalesForce REST API PHP, Not able to see uploaded Attachment

Tags: php, rest, salesforce

I am trying to upoad attachments to a specific case using REST API which I have successfully completed.

the files are being uploaded to that specific case. and I am using base64_encode to send binary data to SalesForce as they required the binary data to be sent.

but the issue is that when I see the files in the sales force control panel, 
all the files are listed there and their size is correct, name is correct etc
but when I view/download any file uploaded with the script it doesn't open. the file shows errror. 
ie. when I upload an png image with the rest API, I wont be able to open the image after downloading from the sales force control panel.

Can any one please help?
I think sales force might not decode the uploaded files back from base64_encode, is that right?

Thanks in advance

here is the code

```
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
$db_img = fread($fp, filesize($file));
$db_img = addslashes($db_img);
$db_img = base64_encode($db_img);
```

and then after encoding I am concatenating $db_img within the body element like this

```
...................

...'.$db_img.'...

.................;
```

Comment: post your code, sounds like it might be getting double encoded.

Comment: @superfell sorry, I have added the code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. I thought I should post the answer as well. I am using the following function to add attachments to the Case Object.

No need to convert to base64 at all

```
public function add_attachment($case_id, $full_file_path, $file_name) {
    $url = $this->instance_url."/services/data/v33.0/chatter/feed-elements";

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");



    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Authorization: OAuth $this->access_token";
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=a7V4kRcFA8E79pivMuV2tukQ85cmNKeoEgJgq';

    $post_text = '--a7V4kRcFA8E79pivMuV2tukQ85cmNKeoEgJgq
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

    {
       "body":{
          "messageSegments":[
             {
                "type":"Text",
                "text":"Task Attachment"
             }
          ]
       },
       "capabilities":{
          "content":{
             "description":"Task Attachment",
             "title":"'.$file_name.'"
          }
       },
       "feedElementType":"FeedItem",
       "subjectId":"'.$case_id.'"
    }

    --a7V4kRcFA8E79pivMuV2tukQ85cmNKeoEgJgq
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="feedElementFileUpload"; filename="'.$file_name.'"
    Content-Type: image/png

    '. file_get_contents($full_file_path).'

    --a7V4kRcFA8E79pivMuV2tukQ85cmNKeoEgJgq--';

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_text);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    $response_json = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    //print_r($info);

    if ( $status != 201 ) {
        $this->errors[] = "Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl);         
        return FALSE;
    }
    $this->status = $status;
    $this->curl_error = curl_error($curl);
    $this->curl_errno = curl_errno($curl);
    return  json_decode($response_json,TRUE);

}
```